# How to use an integer value to represent an up or down run?

Tags: java, arraylist, methods

I am writing a method to find runs in a .txt file by putting them into an `ArrayList<Integer>`. I am confused as to how I should indicate whether a run is going up or down with an `int` value.

I was given this pseudocode for prompting:

> Method FindRuns(In: pList is ArrayList of Integers; int pDir is RUNS_UP or RUNS_DN) Returns ArrayList of Integers

For the method so far I have:

```
private ArrayList<Integer> FindRuns(ArrayList<Integer> pList, int pDir)
```

The pseudocode then prompts a series of else/if statements about whether pDir is RUNS_UP or RUNS_DN. I am unsure what to do at this point.

Here is the full pseudo-code:

```
Method FindRuns(In: pList is ArrayList of Integers; int pDir is RUNS_UP or RUNS_DN) Returns ArrayList of Integers 
    listRunsCount ← arrayListCreate(pList.size(), 0)
    Declare int varaibles i ← 0, k ← 0
    While i < pList.size() - 1 Do 
        If pDir is RUNS_UP and pList element at i is  ≤ pList element at i + 1 Then
            Increment k
        Else If pDir is RUNS_DN and pList element at i is  ≥ pList element at i + 1 Then
            Increment k
        Else If k  0 ≠ Then
            Increment the element at index k of listRunsCount
            k ← 0
        End If
        Increment i
    End While

    If k  0 ≠ Then 
        Increment the element at index k of listRunsCount
    End If

    Return listRunsCount 

End Method FindRuns
```

Comment: can you please , explain by little example ?

Comment: Can you write the `ArrayList<Integer> FindUpRuns(ArrayList<Integer> pList)` method? If so, then write a second method `ArrayList<Integer> FindDownRuns(ArrayList<Integer> pList)`, then consider how you would merge them into one.

Comment: No Tassos the project states to use the FindRuns method to find both. I'll go ahead and post the whole pseudocode for the if/else statements:
While i < pList.size() - 1 Do 
If pDir is RUNS_UP and pList element at i is  ≤ pList element at i + 1 Then Increment k 
ElseIf pDir is RUNS_DN and pList element at i is  ≥ pList element at i + 1 Then Increment k
 Else
 If k  0 ≠ Then Increment the element at index k of listRunsCount
 k ← 0

Comment: Put the pseudo-code into your Question.

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program should probably define constants, like this:

```
public class TheProgram
{
    public static final int RUNS_UP = 1;
    public static final int RUNS_DOWN = 2;

    // place the method you are writing here
}
```

You can then use them in your method like so:

```
if (pDir == RUNS_UP)
{
    // runs up
}
```

and

```
if (pDir == RUNS_DOWN)
{
    // runs down
}
```